# Can't call setState on component that is not mounted

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

This is not updating the state and it is saying "Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Wrapper component."

```
export class Smap extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      my_lat: 1,my_lon: 1
    };
    this.getCoords=this.getCoords.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getCoords();
  }
  getCoords = () =>{
    let a=1;
    let b=1;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      a=position.coords.latitude;
      b=position.coords.longitude;
      console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
      console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
    });
    this.setState({
      my_lat:a,
      my_lon:b
    })
  }   
    render() {
        const containerStyle = {
            position: 'relative',  
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        }
        
        return (
        <div className="Smap-cntr">
          <h1>{this.state.my_lat} {this.state.my_lon}</h1>
          <Map google={this.props.google}
          containerStyle={containerStyle}
          initialCenter={{
            lat: 40.854885,
            lng: -88.081807
          }}
          zoom={1}
          onClick={this.onMapClicked}className="Smap-map" >
            <Marker
                title={`distance is ${d} meters`}
                name={'SOMA'}
                position={{lat: 40.854885,
                  lng: -88.081807}} />
            <Marker
                title={`distance is ${d} meters`}
                name={'SOMA'}
                position={{lat:this.state.my_lat,
                  lng:this.state.my_lon}} />
            <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
                <div>
                  <h1></h1>
                </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          </Map>
          {console.log(lat1,lat2)}
        </div>
        );
      }
    }
 
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ("AIzaSyBXNlWEKkk2l9Yalt5F0Do4hVcMTYWePGE")
})(Smap)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `this.stateState` you have, gets the value directly from the initial values of your variables `a` and `b`. You should put this inside the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. However if you directly put this in your code, it will return an error saying that `setState` is not defined. I assumed that because you are using `function(position)` inside `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. To fix this, you can change this part:

```
getCoords = () =>{
    let a=1;
    let b=1;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      a=position.coords.latitude;
      b=position.coords.longitude;
      console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
      console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
    });
    this.setState({
      my_lat:a,
      my_lon:b
    })
  }
```

to this where I use `position =>` instead of `function(position)`:

```
getCoords = () => {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 1;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      a = position.coords.latitude;
      b = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
      console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
      this.setState({
        my_lat: a,
        my_lon: b
      });
    });
  }
```

Here is a [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-atufbr?file=style.css).

Please remove API key from your question and don't post your API key in public sites in the future. You can also add the `google-maps` tag in your question to increase visibility for those who are following Google Maps tags.